# JqGrid - updating the values in all data cells

Tags: jqgrid

My JqGrid looks like this:

| Staff | Room 1 | Room 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jim | 240 | 120 |
| Dave | 480 | 240 |

The staff and rooms are obtained from tables and are unknown in number at runtime. The figures (data) represent the total time spent by each staff in each room and are in minutes. I have all the above working.

All I want to do now is to iterate over all the data entries and change minutes (Eg: 240) to hours and minutes (EG 4h:0m). I'm ok with doing the math for the conversion, it's the looping over the cells and the reading and updating (just the displayed value) that has defeated me.

This is my code so far for the looping:

```
 var $grid = jQuery('#statstab1grid') 
 var rows  = $grid[0].rows 
 var crows = rows.length
 var irow, row, cellsofrow

 for (irow = 1; irow < crows; irow++) 
 {
  row        = rows[irow];  
  cellsofrow = row.cells;

  alert('$(cellsofrow[0]).text() is ' + $(cellsofrow[0]).text())
  alert('$(cellsofrow[1]).text() is ' + $(cellsofrow[1]).text())
 }
```

The first alert outputs Jim then Dave, the second alert outputs nothing,
just the prompt. Even if I managed to access the data values, how would I write back to the grid the modified values?

Comment: Can you please show the code that you've tried? Also, are you using JavaScript or Typescript? I have done similar work in my projects. But, based on your need, will provide more information. For now, you can refer to getDataIDs here http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods

Comment: Code added as above.

Answer (score 0):

It is good to post which version of jqGrid is used. This one is the important part.

The code you posted and your comments that nothing is alerted for cell index 1, can tell me that maybe you have a hidden field in your colModel, which value is empty. In this case it would be good to post your entire grid setup.

To the problem - you have a lot of options  to do this conversion.

1. You can use custom formatter - more about this you can [find here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/formatters/#custom-formatter). This method is preferred.
2. You can use getRowData (without parameter) to get all the data in the grid and use setRowData to update the values. Be a careful with this method if you have a lot of data in the grid - it will be slowly in this case. See docs for [grid methods](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/user-guide/basic-grid/#methods)
3. If your data is local (array) you can recalculate it, before to put it into the grid